# FPrintf CString printing out only the first letter?

Tags: c++, cstring, printf

I would like to use fprintf to print out some CStrings as well as some more text:

```
CString project = "Project";
FILE * pFile;
CString FileName = project + "_Stats.txt";
pFile = _wfopen(FileName, _T("w"));
fprintf(pFile, "Project Name: %s", project);
```

The file that is created is called "Project_Stats.txt" and the output should be "Project Name: Project" however I get "Project Name: P".  Why does only the first letter get printed out and is there a way I can fix it?

Comment: Is your project compiled as UNICODE?

Comment: @nvoigt: Almost certainly. The ISO-8859-1 subset of Unicode in UTF-16 is encoded as 0000-0080, which on big-endian systems means the second byte is 00.

Answer (score 1):

pm100 has given the correct answer and then deleted it - the correct code for UNICODE `CString` is `%ls`, not `%s`.

Answer (score 0):

```
fprintf(pFile, "Project Name: %s", project.GetBuffer());
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `fprintf(FILE*, char*, ...)` has no idea what type project should have. So the compiler will compile anything like a cast to `void*`. When you want a `char*` you have to use th `GetBuffer()` member of CString.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because CString is in UNICODE, so to write ANSI text to your file first convert it to multi byte, ie:

```
CStringA projectA(project);
```

and then:

```
fprintf(pFile, "Project Name: %s", projectA.GetString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
fprintf(pFile, "Project Name: %s", (const char_t*)project);
```

or

```
fprintf(pFile, "Project Name: %s", (const wchar_t*)project);
```

see this topic for further info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72b2swax.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't have MFC now, but in Win32++ the following works properly (I have 1252 codepage, so Russian chars are not in 1252 codepage, also cpp file is saved as UTF-8 with BOM):

```
Win32xx::CString project{L"Z:\\Projectцц"};
FILE * pFile;
Win32xx::CString FileName{project + L"_Staпрпфts.txt"};
pFile = _wfopen(FileName.GetBuffer(FileName.GetLength()), _T("w, ccs=UTF-16LE"));
fwprintf(pFile, L"Project Name: %s", project.GetBuffer(project.GetLength()));
```

As a note never mix Unicode and ANSI methods in Win32. This also refers to string literals, use _T macro or just always make project Unicode and use L"" for sting literals.
Maybe is better to get used to something like boost::filesystem (which will be included in next standard) for file path handling and C++ streams for formatting. One thing to remember is that proper Unicode handling in Windows is a trial and error method, until you get it right.